# Making Slide movie by Using gallery images and sound file

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make an android simple application in which,
I have one task to perform for my college project work. I have to make one slide movie with .mp4/.avi extension. 
I have some couple of jpg images and mp3 sound file.By merging images and sound file I have to make result movie slide.

Comment: You have not really asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applicaton you are talking about is NOT a simple application.If you really need it you can try to use FFMPEG util compiled for Android to merge photo and audio to one avi file, but if you are not proficient in programming  it will be pretty hard task for you.